# Creating Batch file to create shortcut

Tags: batch-file, shortcut

I can create a shortcut file manually for this location (%windir%\system32\rundll32.exe advapi32.dll,ProcessIdleTasks)

I want to do the same with .bat file (Not .vbs visual basic). I tried this after googling but its not working. Please tell me correct script, and please explain each command.

```
@echo off
echo [InternetShortcut] >> "%AllUsersProfile%\desktop\shortcut.Ink"
echo URL="%windir%\system32\rundll32.exe" >> "%AllUsersProfile%\desktop\shortcut.ink"
```

Comment: may be it works better, if you make it less colourful: it's not `.ink`, it's `.lnk` (`.LNK`)

Comment: You should be echoing `%%WinDir%%` if you want the content to read `%WinDir%`, although `%%SystemRoot%%` is preferable as `%WinDir%` is only kept for legacy reasons. Also, are you aware that modern Operating Systems do not use `%AllUsersProfile%` , they use `%Public%`. That said, any system which doesn't use only `RunDll32` without a path or extension is broken anyhow.

Comment: Well stephan, I changed .ink to .lnk, Now its creating .lnk file but in properties it doesn't have Target tab.

Comment: Compo, I replaced %WinDir% with %%SystemRoot%% and %AllUsersProfile% with %Public% but still it doesn't has Target field in properties.

Answer (score 0):

I present a small hybrid script **[BAT/VBS]** to create a desktop shortcut.
And you can of course modify it to your purpose.

```dos
@echo off
mode con cols=87 lines=5 & color 9B
Title Shortcut Creator for your batch and applications files by Hackoo
Set MyFile=%~f0
Set ShorcutName=HackooTest
(
echo Call Shortcut("%MyFile%","%ShorcutName%"^)
echo ^'**********************************************************************************************^)
echo Sub Shortcut(ApplicationPath,Nom^)
echo    Dim objShell,DesktopPath,objShortCut,MyTab
echo    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell"^)
echo    MyTab = Split(ApplicationPath,"\"^)
echo    If Nom = "" Then
echo    Nom = MyTab(UBound(MyTab^)^)
echo    End if
echo    DesktopPath = objShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop"^)
echo    Set objShortCut = objShell.CreateShortcut(DesktopPath ^& "\" ^& Nom ^& ".lnk"^)
echo    objShortCut.TargetPath = Dblquote(ApplicationPath^)
echo    ObjShortCut.IconLocation = "Winver.exe,0"
echo    objShortCut.Save
echo End Sub
echo ^'**********************************************************************************************
echo ^'Fonction pour ajouter les doubles quotes dans une variable
echo Function DblQuote(Str^)
echo    DblQuote = Chr(34^) ^& Str ^& Chr(34^)
echo End Function
echo ^'**********************************************************************************************
) > Shortcutme.vbs
Start /Wait Shortcutme.vbs
Del Shortcutme.vbs
::***************************************Main Batch*******************************************
cls
echo Done and your main batch goes here !
echo i am a test 
Pause > Nul
::********************************************************************************************
```

Comment: Hackoo, your script makes a .bat file, but i want to make .lnk file for this target (%windir%\system32\rundll32.exe) on desktop (No visual basic). Just simple is that. Please share a simple script with least commands posssible (target, destination, shorcut name).